# Wrong host sending SMTP

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a mail using javax.mail. This is my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();        
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
props.setProperty("mail.user", user);
props.setProperty("mail.password", password);   

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
```

But I get this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.wrong.server.com, port: 25;
```

The funny thing is that "smtp.wrong.server.com" isn't the value that I'm passing as host.

It is like Session.getDefaultInstance(props) is returning an already created session with the wrong host name.

There isn't any other place inside my EAR where javax.mail is used (at least not in my code, maybe inside a third party dependecy?).

This behaviour only happens, of course, in PRO environment. The same EAR deployed in DEV and TEST env works fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To confirm you are loading correct properties just try to print them after assigning.

Comment: See the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in the JavaMail FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Session.getDefaultInstance. I should use Session.getInstance

From javadoc:

**getDefaultInstance**

(...)the default session is potentially available to all code executing in the same Java virtual machine(...)Subsequent calls return the Session object that was created by the first call, and ignore the passed Properties object. Use the getInstance method to get a new Session object every time the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

It seams your are not using the correct key for your proerties. see Javadoc for [javax.mail.Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance%28java.util.Properties%29)

> It is expected that the client supplies values for the properties
>   listed in Appendix A of the JavaMail spec (particularly
>   mail.store.protocol, mail.transport.protocol, mail.host, mail.user,
>   and mail.from) as the defaults are unlikely to work in all cases.